# Xcode 6.1 NSLayoutConstraint no know class method issue

Tags: xcode6.1-gm-seed, ios8.1

I upgraded my iPhone 5 to iOS 8.1 and XCode to 6.1 (which turns out a tragedy), I then test my custom keyboard using them. At first, everything was ok, I can run my custom keyboard on simulators and on my device with no issue, but suddenly, building the app against my device gave me

No know class method for selector 'constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:contant:'

The weird part is I did not change anything on this part of code.
And building it against simulators passed fine, it even built fine if I removed my device and archive it against 'iOS Device'.

I then created a ad-hoc build and install it on my 'problematic' device using iTunes, it works fine.

I am totally lost, here, anyone has any idea?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I tried to install a clean Yosemite and a clean XCode 6.1 with new code signing identity on my other Mac and this does the trick...I will try to use a new code signing identity on my main iMac and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error with Xcode 6.1 building for iPad Air on the iOS Simulator.  Not sure what the cause was but I did find a solution / workaround.  I deleted the Derived Data folder ('your username'/Library/Developer/XCode/Derived Data) and the issue disappeared.  I have been able to build my app for all of the simulated devices and install and run it on an iPad Air (iOS 8.1).